# How to set up line type in plot.xts?

Tags: r, plot, xts

I have multiple (about 10) time series and I want to draw lines using `plot.xts`. I don't know how set up types of line, i.e., dashed line, solid line, etc., in the function of `plot.xts`. I do have found some discussions on color setting but without any findings on this issue. Can anyone give me some hint or directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

visual parameters of plot you should know are

`lwd` - width of the line

`lty` - 1 = solid , 2 = dashed , 3 = dotted.

if you want to draw multiple lines on the same graph plot the first one using `plot` and the others using `lines`.

Comment: @user1461289: if this answers your question, you should click the check mark. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).